# Advantage of using Dinic's O((V^2)E) algorithm over Edmond-Karp algorithm O(V(E^2))

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

Is there any advantage of using Dinic's O((V^2)E) algorithm over  Edmond-Karp algorithm O(V(E^2))?
In other words, I want to know how is O((V^2)E) better than O(V(E^2)) if it is from a Competitive Programming point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the total number of vertices in n. "Usually", number of edges in a connected graph tend to be between n and n^2.

Mostly the input graphs are not very sparse, so the number of edges in maximum percentage of the cases would be greater than n (might be O(n log n), or in the worst case, O(n^2)).

So, if you consider the worst case scenario, O(V^2 * E) is O(n^4), whereas O(V*E^2) is O(n^5). Hence you see the advantage of using an O(V^2*E) time algorithm over O(V*E^2).

Comment: I also thought this might be the reason. Can you prove it?

Comment: I'm not sure if I get you. What exactly do you want me to prove?